# Can you rotate secrets with ECS and Fargate?

Tags: amazon-ecs, aws-fargate, secret-key, aws-secrets-manager

I've been trying to find information about rotating secrets with AWS Secrets Manager and ECS with Fargate and I've learned that you can use it to avoid putting sensitive data on your images, but I can't find anything about being able to rotate secrets, I'm starting to wonder if it's even possible.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/rotating-secrets.html says that auto rotation is possible. Are you facing some specific error/problem while trying to enable it / use it ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use use Secrets Manager with Fargate by embedding the secret in the task definition, and you can enable rotation of secrets in the Secrets Manager console.

The problem is if you enable rotation, you have to ensure your container picks up  the new secret. This means the old secret has to be valid for the life of the container, or the container needs to refresh the secret. A [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58652282/how-to-use-new-secret-created-by-key-rotation-from-aws-secrets-manager/59167837#59167837) discusses the strategies for dealing with rotation in applications. The short answer is if this is a DB accessed in a Java application, you might look at the [Secrets Manager provided JDBC driver wrapper](https://github.com/aws/aws-secretsmanager-jdbc).