# Scheduled password rotation in Node/Express using Knex.js

Tags: node.js, express, knex.js, aws-secrets-manager

I'm developing a Node/Express application using Knex.js for database communication. The database password is fetched from AWS Secrets Manager when the application is started. I would like to set up a scheduled (daily) password rotation.

Is there a way to update the database connection with a new password in Knex.js during runtime? And how would that look like? I would like to avoid restarting the entire application.

Comment: You can restart your server each time there was a password rotation

Answer (score 0):

Secrets Manager provides a few [rotation strategies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/rotating-secrets-lambda-function-customizing.html). In all of these strategies the application must either only establish the DB connection once or refresh the secret periodically. More detail can be found in the prior [how to use new secret created by key rotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58652282/how-to-use-new-secret-created-by-key-rotation-from-aws-secrets-manager/59167837#59167837) question.

It looks like the Kinex.js framework allows you to specify a configuration object and refresh time. It seems like you can use that along with the multi-user rotation strategy for any long lived application to provide continuous service.

Comment: I don't know anyone who has been using that feature... it might or might not work. I cannot recall the original usecase why that configuration refers time was added, but I know it was not for whole config. There becomes problem for example what to do to old connections, which are still active in the pool (in this case I suppose that old connections keep working just fine though)...

Comment: It's true that the Knex configuration allows you to add an "expirationChecker"-function which runs every time a new connection is established between the node application and the database. If I understand it correctly the connection is closed after a period of inactivity which in turn would lead to the expirationChecker being called in the next request. We cannot expect this scenario to occur in our case since we have a quite even flow of incoming requests. Please correct me if I'm wrong